# User Information List - Duplicate Accounts

Tags: 2010, user-accounts

I was looking at the hidden User Information List on a claims based site and noticed that some users have two entries, one for the claims version of their account (i:0#.w|domain\user) and one non-claims (domain\user). Why would they both exist

It also caused an issue when a user was added to an item via a user column. It was added as the non claims account, when i wanted the claims version (as the user is logged into the site as this)

Can the non-claims ones be removed?

David